# BATCH - How to echo a line with a set /P command to another file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file which gathers some enviromental data and uses it to build another batch file.
I have a problem with passing the line which contains a set /P command using an echo command.

My code:

```
echo smthnsmthn >> batch.bat
echo set /P var=<file.txt >> batch.bat
echo smthnsmthn >> batch.bat
```

The problem is that the line containing the set /P command is missing in the output batch.bat file.

I've tried to replace the set command with

```
echo for /f "delims=" %%%x in (file.txt) do set "var=%%%x" >> batch.bat
```

but the result is the same.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(   echo smthnsmthn
    echo set /P var=^<file.txt
    echo smthnsmthn
) > batch.bat
```

You need to escape the `<` so it is not seen as an input redirect in the generating batch, but as normal character